# Why is a mold required in isostatic pressing after performing Sintering

Tags: mechanical-engineering, metallurgy

After an a object is formed through direct laser sintering, as a post-processing procedure the object is sent for hot-isostatic pressing, In hot isostatic pressing the sintered object is placed in a mold and then pressure and heat are applied.
I was wondering what would go wrong if the bare object without the mold  was made to undergo pressing? Remember the sintered object already has a shape acquired during sintering so it may need a mold to get a specific shape during pressing.   My assumption- In hot isostatic pressing the object might get softened and hence deformed due to heat and thus the requirement of a mold to keep the object firm. Is this assumption true??
And apart from deformation are there any other undesirable effects caused to the un-molded object during hot isostatic pressing?

Comment: If the mold is not there to provide the final shape - what shape will you get after pressing?

Comment: @SolarMike Oh I forgot to add something in the question. Ill edit the question.